# How to fix RuntimeError "Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument"?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, pytorch

I'm trying to train a classifier via PyTorch. However, I am experiencing problems with training when I feed the model with training data.
I get this error on `y_pred = model(X_trainTensor)`:

> RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'

Here are key parts of my code:

```py
# Hyper-parameters 
D_in = 47  # there are 47 parameters I investigate
H = 33
D_out = 2  # output should be either 1 or 0
```

```py
# Format and load the data
y = np.array( df['target'] )
X = np.array( df.drop(columns = ['target'], axis = 1) )
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8)  # split training/test data

X_trainTensor = torch.from_numpy(X_train) # convert to tensors
y_trainTensor = torch.from_numpy(y_train)
X_testTensor = torch.from_numpy(X_test)
y_testTensor = torch.from_numpy(y_test)
```

```py
# Define the model
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
    nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1)
)
```

```py
# Define the loss function
loss_fn = torch.nn.NLLLoss()
```

```py
for i in range(50):
    y_pred = model(X_trainTensor)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_trainTensor)
    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():       
        for param in model.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad
```

Comment: Did it tell you what line of code that is triggering a Runtime Error?

Comment: Yes, in my last code block. `y_pred = model(X_trainTensor)` triggers it.

Comment: I don't use PyTorch, but could you possibly use `model(float(X_trainTensor))`

Comment: I then get the following error on the same line:
`ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Additionally, if I cast the tensor to all floats. I get a new error: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'dim'`

Comment: Hmm, I found [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2138). You can check there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195473/discussion-between-milkyway90-and-shawn-zhang).

Comment: Which line in the code do you use as your input?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Reference is from [this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2138).

When the error is `RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'`, you would need to use the `.float()` function since it says `Expected object of scalar type Float`.

Therefore, the solution is changing `y_pred = model(X_trainTensor)` to `y_pred = model(X_trainTensor.float())`.

Likewise, when you get another error for `loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_trainTensor)`, you need `y_trainTensor.long()` since the error message says `Expected object of scalar type Long`.

You could also do `model.double()`, as suggested by @Paddy
.

Answer (score 59):

Before converting to `Tensor`, try this

```
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue can be fixed by setting the datatype of input to Double i.e `torch.float32`

I hope the issue came because your datatype is `torch.float64`.

You can avoid such situations either while setting the data, as explained in one of other answers or make the model type also to the same as of your data. i.e use either float64 or float32.

For debug, print obj.dtype and check for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do that:

```
df['target'] = df['target'].astype(np.float32)
```

and for x features too

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also occur if the wrong loss function is selected. For example, if you have regression problem, but you are trying to use cross entropy loss. Then it will be fixed by changing your loss function on MSE

Answer (score 1):

try to use:
target = target.float() # target is the name of error

Answer (score 1):

New to PyTorch. For some reason, calling `torch.set_default_dtype()` with the needed datatype was what worked for me on Google Colab. `network.double()`/`network.float()` and `tensor.double()`/`tensor.float()` didn’t have any effect, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150377/1976597), to convert all columns of one type to another...

```py
df.update(df.select_dtypes("float64").astype("float32"))
```

Note that this is an in-place operation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this example:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import numpy as np
import torch

a = np.array([0, 1,2])
b = [[0, 1,2], [4, 5,6], [7,8,9]]

bb = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    bb[i,:] = np.array(b[i])


a = torch.from_numpy(a)
b = torch.from_numpy(bb)

a= a.float()
b = b.float()

cosine_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(b, a)
print(cosine_scores)
```