# PyTorch: Error>> expected scalar type float but found double

Tags: python, pytorch

I've just started using pytorch and I am trying a simple **multi-layer perceptron** . My ReLU Activation Function is the following:

```
def ReLU_activation_func(outputs):
    print(type(outputs))
    result = torch.where(outputs > 0, outputs, 0.)
    result = float(result)
    return result
```

So I am trying to maintain the value which is greater than 0 and change the value to 0 if the value is smaller than 0.
And this is a part of the main code where I use the ReLU Function (where I have the error):

```
def forward_pass(train_loader):
    for batch_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
        print(image.size())
        x = image.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        print(x.size())
    
        input_node_num = 28 * 28
        hidden_node_num = 100
        output_node_num = 10
        W_ih = torch.rand(input_node_num, hidden_node_num)
        W_ho = torch.rand(hidden_node_num, output_node_num)
        final_output_n = ReLU_activation_func(torch.matmul(x, W_ih))
```

and when I run the code, I get the following error:

```py
RuntimeError:
1 forward_pass(train_loader)

in forward_pass(train_loader)
-----14         W_ih = torch.rand(input_node_num, hidden_node_num)
-----15         W_ho = torch.rand(hidden_node_num, output_node_num)
---->16         final_output_n = ReLU_activation_func(torch.matmul(x, W_ih))

in ReLU_activation_func(outputs)
-----10     print(type(outputs))
---->11     result = torch.where(outputs > 0, outputs, 0.)
-----12     result = float(result)
-----13     return result

RuntimeError: expected scalar type float but found double
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix RuntimeError "Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741087/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-expected-object-of-scalar-type-float-but-got-scalar-typ)

Comment: I changed the type using "result.float()" but the same error shows up at the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not on `result`, it's either on `X`, `W_ih`, or `torch.where(outputs > 0, outputs, 0.)`.

If you don't set an argument for the `dtype` of [`torch.rand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rand.html), it will assign the dtype based on the pytorch's global default value.

The global variable can be changed using [`torch.set_default_tensor_type()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_tensor_type.html#torch.set_default_tensor_type).

Or go the easy route:

```
def ReLU_activation_func(outputs):
    print((outputs).dtype)
    result = torch.where(outputs > 0, outputs, torch.zeros_like(outputs)).float()
    return result

# for the forward pass function, convert the tensor to floats before matmul
def forward_pass(train_loader):
    for batch_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
        ... <your code>
        X, W_ih = X.float(), W_ih.float()
        final_output_n = ReLU_activation_func(torch.matmul(x, W_ih))
```

Comment: I used your easy route but then I get this error: "zeros_like(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray"  at code line "result = torch.where(outputs > 0, outputs, torch.zeros_like(outputs)).float()"

Comment: when I print(type(outputs)), it shows <class 'torch.Tensor'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'> as if outputs has two data types

Comment: that means that the `output` is a `numpy.array`. should've used ` `result = numpy.where(th.numpy() > 0, th.numpy(), numpy.zeros_like(th.numpy()))` and if you want to the output to be a torch tensor you can add `result = torch.from_numpy(result)` before returning `result`

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you so much :) Love you <3