# Float64 Normalisation in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

So when I want to do normalization to float64 in deep learning, I need to make float64_max to be 1 or just every image’s max value as 1?

I read a .nii file to get a 3D array with type float64 and its value is very big. I need to normalize it into 0-1 and float32 type to input my deep learning model. So I was wondering which normalization way is better or correct.

Make float64_max to be 1:

```py
return torch.tensor(img / sys.float_info.max).to(torch.float32)
```

Make every image's max value as 1:

```py
return torch.nn.functional.normalize(torch.tensor(img)).to(torch.float32)
```

Also, because the float64 range is much bigger than float32, when I do `return torch.tensor(img / sys.float_info.max).to(torch.float32)`, the value have a chance to be all 0.

Comment: https://pinkr1ver.com/posts/2022-04-06-data-type-is-medical-image-normalization-trap/

Answer (score 1):

No, you should normalize the max possible value of all images to 1 not the maximum value of each image separately.

For a general image RGB 8-bit image, the maximum value for a pixel channel is 255, so you could divide the entire image's channel value by 255.
In this way, you will obtain a new image of type `float32` (or `float64`) with all pixel's channel values in the range `[0, 1]`, but the min is not always 0 and max is not always 1.

Comment: Thanks. I think this normalization will be very suitable. To be more clear, the question here is that my dataset is .nii files which are not general RGB 8-bit images and their type is float64. So I think I can divide float64_max like RGB 8-bit image divide 255 to normalize.  The question here is that I can not input model with float64 tensor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741087/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-expected-object-of-scalar-type-float-but-got-scalar-typ I got the answer.Thanks anyway!